# File count of a directory in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I would like to know how can I get the total amount of archives inside of a directory, for example desktop.
I don't just want to know what's inside of the root of the directory, but also inside of its subfolders.

To just get the archives on the root of desktop I can do the following:

```
NSArray *directoryContent  = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfFileInFolder = [directoryContent  count];
```

But I need to get also the count of its subfolders.

Can somebody help me?

**Edit:
Finally I have coded this way:**

```
-(int) numberOfDocumentsInPath: (NSString *) path{
    NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator* totalSubpaths = [manager enumeratorAtPath: path];

    NSLog(@"Path %@ has %d documents", path, (int)[[totalSubpaths allObjects] count]);

    return (int)[[totalSubpaths allObjects] count];
}
```

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCFileManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from [the docs](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/EnumADir.html):

> If you need to recurse into subdirectories, use
>   enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler: as
>   shown in “Using a Directory Enumerator”).

Check also here:
[Using a Directory Enumerator](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/EnumADir.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 NSDirectoryEnumerator *subs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:FolderPath error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift version:

```
var subs = NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil) as! [String]
var filecount = subs.count
println(filecount)

for sub in subs {
    //Do stuff with files
}
```